# Incompatible types: 'TFormStyle' and 'TTeeFontStyle'

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, delphi-2009

I have written a code with **Delphi 2009** and updated my **CodeGear Delphi to XE2**. It compiled perfectly with **Delphi 2009**, but now it doesn't ! It gives me this error instead :

**[DCC Error]  Incompatible types: 'TFormStyle' and 'TTeeFontStyle'**!
I tried creating a new *Vcl Forms Application* and wrote the command that generates this error :

```
Form1.FormStyle := FsNormal;
```

and it compiled perfectly too,I don't know why is this happening, although I believe there's nothing wrong with my syntax, please help, thanks.
This is the code that is not compiling :

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG;
var Handled: Boolean);
begin
begin
KeyPreview := True;
case Msg.message of
WM_KEYDOWN:
  if Msg.wParam = 27 then
  begin
    form1.Menu:=mainmenu1;
    fullscreen1.Checked:=false;
    form1.formstyle:=fsnormal;
    form1.BorderStyle:=bssizeable;
  end
  else
  if msg.wParam=VK_f5 then
  begin
    browser.Navigate(memo2.Text);
  end;
  end;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is name conflict with some TeeChart module, which is in "use" clause. You can write full-qualified identificator name to resolve this problem:

```
formstyle := Vcl.Forms.fsnormal;
```

P.S. Note that I deleted `"form1."` qualifier also. Normally it is not very useful in the form method body, and sometimes even harmful (imagine that you have multiple instances of TForm1)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the answer of MBo, I think it is better to use:

```
Self.formstyle := Vcl.Forms.fsnormal;
```

When you have multiple instances of TForm1, this will always adjust the instance you are using at that moment.

Comment: Why an answer that duplicates the side-point in an answer, which actually also answered the question, getting votes?

Comment: Sertac, because I do not have enough rep to make a comment on the earlier answer this was my only option (an attempt to edit Mbo answer was rejected). I've also seen that MBo has updated his answer.

Comment: @RFerwerda - Mbo's answer had that information before it was modified. I wasn't asking why you posted an answer. I was wondering why your answer was getting votes although it didn't add anything to the already existing answer. My question wasn't particularly addressed to you..

Answer (score 0):

Qualify the value with the particular enum type that it comes from:

```
Form1.FormStyle := TFormStyle.fsNormal;
```

Or even:

```
Form1.FormStyle := Vcl.Forms.TFormStyle.fsNormal;
```